# Locate Current location marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code is to locate a current location marker for the user on google map by clicking on the button , geocode function will receive the address information .

how can i make the address take the current location value not the input value ?

http://jsfiddle.net/razanrab/WppF6/253/

```
<body>
  <div id="panel">
      <input id="city_country" type="textbox" value="Berlin, Germany">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>  
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>


//js 

var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

codeAddress = function () {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var address = document.getElementById('city_country').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 16,
            streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
              mapTypeIds:[google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP] 
    },
    center: results[0].geometry.location,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the current location from the user, you will need to use the geolocation API. Please see the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }
```

What you can do is use the variable above, pos, to set as the marker's location and the center of the map instead of the result of the geocode query like in your sample. This will center the map around the user's location instead of the location geocoded from the textbox.

I was able to use the JSFiddle you provided along with some code of my own and from our geolocation sample I linked above. I believe this is what you are looking for(Please be advised you will need to put your own API key into this JSFiddle for it to work) It will geolocate the user's position and allow the user to drag the marker and get address info just like in your sample. This will also allow the user to click the geocode button and still have the same functionality:

https://jsfiddle.net/45z4841z/1/

I hope this helps!